# Unique values from Kernel Density

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, kernel-density, unique-value

I have calculated Kernel Density for feature class "fc" using following code:

`dens = KernelDensity(fc,"NONE", 1, SearchRadius, "SQUARE_METERS", "DENSITIES", "PLANAR")`

The raster attribute table:

[image]

I have then saved the raster as lyr file.

I can apply "Unique Values" in the symbology tab.
However:

`lyr.symbologyType
Out[30]: u'OTHER'`

How can i modify my raster, so that symbologyType = "UniqueValues"?

I am using:
ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1
Python 2.7, 32bit

EDIT

I found a workaround:
Convert raster to polygon, setting field "Value" as raster field. 
In the new polygon the field "GRIDCODE" now contains the unique values